# Total Expectation formula, for CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

If have a random variables $X\in [0,1]$ for which i know: 
$$ F(R) = E(d(X) | X \leq R)$$ 
for any $R \in [0,1]$.

I would like to express 
$$ P = E(d(g(X))$$ 
in terms of $F(R)$. the function $g$ is well-behaved, i.e., monotonic, continuous and differentiable with g(0)=0, g(1)=1.

I expect the result to be of the form:

$$ P = \int_0^1 F(R)h(R) dR $$

I have the following intuitive direction:
$$\frac{d}{dR}F(R) dR=f(R)dR \approx E(d(X) | X = R) dR$$

\begin{align}
P &= E(d(g(X)) \\
&= \int_{R} E(d(g(X) | X = R)dR \\
&= \int_{R} E(d(g(X) | g(X) = g(R))dR \\
&= \int_{R} f(g(R))dR
\end{align}

I am a bit stuck here. I expect some kind of change of variable here and even using integration by parts to get back to use $F$ instead of $f$.

Comment: What is the function $d$? Any assumptions on it?

Comment: I can assume that $d$ is positive and bounded